# How to Manage Accessibility Font/Display Size in Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a custom toolbar for a business-sim game I'm working on. This toolbar has 2 rows but I'm seeing an issue with the first one when testing the app on maximum font size and display size through the accessibility settings in Android. Baiscally the text size gets to a point where they're overflowing off screen and how it's written right now the `toolbarCash` gets cut off and I'm seeing "My Game Company $1,000,000,".

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/materialToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarCompanyTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="My Game Company"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarCash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="$1,000,000,000"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--second row-->
        ...
```

I've tried using the `maxLines` and the `autoSizeTextType`/`autoSizeMaxTextSize`. I don't want the text to wrap to a new line but rather just scale to the maximum possible size that would allow all the data to be shown. I've also tried adding `<supports-screens android:resizeable="false" />` in the Manifest but still did not see the desired results.